# Empty space appears at the top of ListView when removing Groups

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewgroup

My music player uses ListView in Details mode to show tracks, and ListViewGroup to group albums tracks together.

I have created event that removes all tracks in one album, when album's ListViewGroup is middle-clicked. Works fine if ListView is not scrolled down when removing tracks. If ListView is scrolled down, album will be removed, but large non-clickable empty space appears at the top of ListView, between headers and first group.

First image, 3 albums in ListView (scrolled up)

[image]

---

Second image, last album removed, everything's fine!

[image]

---

Ok, then ListView is scrolled down when removing one group of items

Third image, 3 albums in ListView (scrolled down)

[image]

---

Fourth image, last album removed, empty space appeared at the top, and last tracks if ListView is not showing at all!

[image]

---

I don't think this has anything to do with my code, but rather a bug in ListView? Anyone noticed same behavior? Is there any trick to prevent this from happening?

---

EDIT: added code which removes items (as user requested it)

```
List<ListViewItem> delItems = new List<ListViewItem>(); // creating list of items to be removed

foreach (ListViewGroup group in listView1.Groups)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(group.Tag) == groupNumber) // all groups have individual number in tag field
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in group.Items)
        {
            delItems.Add(item);
        }
    }
}

foreach (ListViewItem item in delItems)
{
    item.Remove();
}
```

EDIT2: added code to check if group was clicked

Since there is no real way to handle group click, I made it ugly way. But it works.
First of all, I used MouseDown event in ListView. Then I check whether there is an item where user clicks. If user clicks group, then the item is null, and for loop increases i and checks if item can be found now. When eventually item found, we know that the item belongs to the group we clicked. So we get items group tag, where I keep record of what group it is.

```
private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item;

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) // group height is not more that 25 pixels.
    {
        item = listView1.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y + i);

        if (item != null)
        {
            if (i > 1) // bigger than 1, because there is 1 pixel gap between listviewitems when using groups
            {
                if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle) removePlaylistGroup(Convert.ToInt32(item.Group.Tag));
            }
            else
            {
                if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle) removePlaylistItem(item.Index);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it when running it on a different machine?  I agree with you assessment that it probably isn't something with your code, but I've never seen that happen before.

Comment: Yes, it's happening in another Win7 and also in Win8.1.

Comment: @darx: Can you show us the code that removes the items?

Comment: @TaW: Code added to original question.

Answer (score 0):

All this was happening because removing items from `ListView` apparently fires `Form1_Layout` event. In there, I use `listView1.BeginUpdate() ...` to resize listView1, if the form layout changes. Somehow that messes up my listView.

Comment: I suggest framing the deletion loop with a `listView1.SuspendLayout() - listView1.ResumeLayout()` pair.  BTW, how do you catch the Group Click? I know I can subclass the ListView and override WndProc to catch it; I don't know however how to __identify the Group__ that got clicked..!?

Comment: Nothing to do with Suspend/ResumeLayout().  The diagnostic here is a missing call to ListView.EndUpdate().  But really, don't call BeginUpdate() in the Layout event handler.  It should only be used if you make bulk-changes to the Items collection.  If you have flicker problems then fix them by deriving your own class from ListView and set its DoubleBuffered property to true in the constructor.

Comment: @TaW: I added code to show how to determine group click. Feel free to ask if you don't undestand my explanation :P

Comment: @HansPassant: I removed beginupdate from Layout. I'm handling flickering issue by filtering out WM_ERASEBKGND message, so background is not drawn again and again when something happens in listview. Works perfectly. Doublebuffering is enabled too.

Comment: Ugh, I expect to see you back soon with a complaint about poor looking text in the listview.

Comment: @HansPassant: I have used it for weeks now, and no problems at all. All is drawn correcly, and no flicker at all.

Comment: @darx : Thanks for the code. Ugly? Yes but it works. At least as long as one doesn't click on SubItems..

Comment: @TaW: I use subitems, as you can see in screenshots. You can freely click on those. If you click on group, removePlaylistGroup() method is fired, and by clicking items/subitems, it fires removePlaylistItem(). So no problem so far :)